# "Your project stopped working" error when constructing an object and outputing it

Tags: c++, class

Can you help me fix this run-time error? When I compile and run it, it says **"your project stopped working"**.

This is the program. I have 2 constructors with parameters, 1 destructor, 1 copy-constructor, `operator=`, `opertator>>` and `operator<<` overloading, and accessor functions (get and set). I have to mention that for this project I create 5 classes, and the other 4 worked except this one...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Badge
{

private:
    char *badgeType;
    char *badgeName;
    char user[50];

public:

    Badge(char *type, char* name, char *user)
    {   
        this->badgeType = new char[strlen(type) + 1];
        strcpy(this->badgeType, type);
        this->badgeName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(this->badgeName, name);
        strcpy(user, user);
    }

    Badge(char *name, char *user)
    {
        this->badgeType = NULL;
        this->badgeName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(this->badgeName, name);
        strcpy(user, user);

    }

    Badge(const Badge &source)
    {
        if (source.badgeName == NULL)
            this->badgeName = NULL;
        else
        {
            this->badgeName = new char[strlen(source.badgeName) + 1];
            strcpy(this->badgeName, source.badgeName);
        }

        if (source.badgeType == NULL)
            this->badgeType = NULL;
        else
        {
            this->badgeType = new char[strlen(source.badgeType) + 1];
            strcpy(this->badgeType, source.badgeType);
        }
        strcpy(user, source.user);
    }

    ~Badge()
    {
        if (this->badgeName)
            delete[] this->badgeName;
        if (this->badgeType)
            delete[] this->badgeType;
    }

    Badge operator=(const Badge &source)
    {

        if (this->badgeName)
            delete[] this->badgeName;

        if (source.badgeName == NULL)
            this->badgeName = NULL;
        else
        {
            this->badgeName = new char[strlen(source.badgeName) + 1];
            strcpy(this->badgeName, source.badgeName);
        }


        if (this->badgeType)
            delete[] this->badgeType;

        if (source.badgeType == NULL)
            this->badgeType = NULL;
        else
        {
            this->badgeType = new char[strlen(source.badgeType) + 1];
            strcpy(this->badgeType, source.badgeType);
        }

        strcpy(user, source.user);

        return *this;
    }

    char *getBadgeName()
    {
        return badgeName;
    }

    void setBadgeName(char *newBadgeName)
    {
        if (strlen(newBadgeName) == 0)
            cout << "Please enter a valid name.";
        else
        {
            delete[] badgeName;
            badgeName = new char[strlen(newBadgeName) + 1];
            strcpy(badgeName, newBadgeName);
        }
    }

    char *getBadgeType()
    {
        return badgeType;
    }

    void setBadgeType(char *newBadgeType)
    {
        if (strlen(newBadgeType) == 0)
            cout << "Please enter a valid type.";
        else
        {
            delete[] badgeType;
            badgeType = new char[strlen(newBadgeType) + 1];
            strcpy(badgeType, newBadgeType);
        }
    }

    char *getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    void setUser(char *newUser)
    {
        if (strlen(newUser) == 0)
            cout << "Please enter a valid user.";
        else

            strcpy(user, newUser);

    }

    void readBadge()
    {
        cout << "Badge name: "<< endl;
        cin >> badgeName;

        cout << "Badge type: " << endl;
        cin >> badgeType;

        cout << "User who owns the badge: " << endl;
        cin >> user;

    }

    void writeBadge()
    {
        cout << "Badge name: " << badgeName << endl;
        cout << "Badge type: " << badgeType << endl;
        cout << "user who owns the badge: " << user << endl;

    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& consola, Badge &b);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& consola, Badge &b);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& consola, Badge &b)
{

    consola << "Badge type: " << b.getBadgeType();

    consola << "Badge name: " << b.getBadgeName();

    consola << "User who owns the badge: " << b.getUser();

    return consola;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& consola, Badge &b)
{
    cout << "Badge name: ";
    char buffer[30];
    consola >> buffer;
    b.setBadgeName(buffer);
    cout << "Badge type: ";
    char buffer1[20];
    consola >> buffer1[20];
    b.setBadgeType(buffer1);

    cout << "User who owns the badge: ";
    char buffer2[20];
    consola >> buffer2;
    b.setUser(buffer2);

    return consola;
}

int main()
{
    Badge b1("Type1", "Name1", "User101");
    cout << endl << b1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can we fix the error if we don't even know it is?

Comment: Do not tell anybody what error you have. That would make it more interesting to guess.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  Please edit your post with the information, including variable names and values.

Comment: when i compile it says "your project stoped working"

Comment: Sure it can be fixed, starting with using `std::string` instead of `new char[]` and pointers.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the `this->` notation, as this is C++ and not Java.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but it sure is interesting: `strcpy(user, user);`

Comment: ugh, if you really don't want to use `std::string`, at least use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Pointers passed to members should be declared as "pointers to constant data", e.g. `char const * name`. When returning pointers, the pointer type should also be "pointer to constant data".

Comment: What happens if the User enters more than 50 letters for their name?  I recommend, if you don't want to use `std::string`, use `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: In your `operator <<` method, pass the badge by constant reference, since you are not changing it.

Comment: this vector user[50] it is a condition for my POO project. Personally i didn't wanted to use any static vector. In every class i need to have one static vector and one dynamic

Comment: The `main` function returns an `int`.  Always.

Comment: Actually, `strcpy(user, user);` may indeed be the source of your crash. You're overwriting a string literal with itself, and that's undefined behavior.

Comment: It is funny, you use `this->` where you do not really need it and one place where you do need it you do not use it.

Comment: When you write code, start with something simple that works perfectly, then build up. Develop new functionality in isolation, test at every step and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: OMG it worked!!

Comment: the crash was indeed from strcpy(user,user).  i rewrite it like this; Badge(char *type, char* name, char *USER)
 {
  this->badgeType = new char[strlen(type) + 1];
  strcpy(this->badgeType, type);
  this->badgeName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
  strcpy(this->badgeName, name);
  strcpy(user, USER);
 }

Comment: @MihaelaMiki -- Your `main` program does not test the functionality or the viability of copying and assigning your `Badge` object.  What if you did `Badge b2 = b1; Badge b3("abc", "123"); b3 = b3;`  Prepare for more debugging.

Comment: @MihaelaMiki The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your constructor:  the target and source name for the `strcpy(user,user)` are the same.  In fact you copy the parameter content onto itself and leave the `user` array in the object uninitialized.  This is the only place in this constructor, where you'd need a `this->`:

```
Badge(char *type, char* name, char *user)
{   
    badgeType = new char[strlen(type) + 1];
    strcpy(badgeType, type);
    badgeName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(badgeName, name);
    strcpy(this->user, user);
}
```

---

***Edit:*** as Slava mentionned in the comments, if you pass pointer or reference parameters that are not meant to be changed, you should declare them as `const` : this would spot these kind of subtle mismatches at compile time

```
Badge(const char *type, const char* name, const char *user)
```

---

***Edit 2:*** I can't resist to suggest using `string` instead of `char*` and `char[]` if you are allowed:  then you'd no longer have to worry about memory allocations and `strcpy()`. And you could rely on the default copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor.

Comment: You should add that parameters must be of type `const char *` and that would actually help to identify the issue at compile time

Comment: @Slava yes, that's a good idea

Comment: Not quite correct note, OP must change parameters to `const char *` to make this program to be correct as string literals passed. It compiles only by historical reasons to be compatible with C.

Comment: You should resist answering debugging questions that are ill-posed. Peeps like you are the reason peeps like the OP keep posting them!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I can't resist helping lost people when they are sincerly trying by themselves. 77% of the user ask only one question on SO, so not answering because the question is not perfect will not help them to improve.  I suggest reading https://dzone.com/articles/i-stopped-contributing-to-stack-overflow-but-its-n and https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.6cm2ky2qt

Comment: @Christophe: I have read those before. I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/tour. This is _not_ a one-on-one help site.